# python: where do user defined classes override object's __setattr__ method?

Tags: python

I came to a pitfall trying to understand where does the `__setattr__` method of user defined classes is set to objects in python 3.

as my understanding of attributes goes when I type:

```
x.y = z
```

in python code. what happens is that the `__setattr__` function of x is called with the key 'y' and the value of z.

but then I wrote this code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

obj = object()

class A(object):
    pass

a = A()

a.tmp = 123456
obj.tmp = 123456
```

this code crashes on the last line with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in 
    obj.tmp = 123456
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'tmp'
```

I expected lines 10 and 11 to behave the same since I did not override the `__setattr__` methods of object in A.

why did the behavior change between object and A?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with setattr or setattribute.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Doesn't it? Or do `__dict__` assignments not pass through `__setattr__`?

Comment: They may do, but that wasn't my point: the `__setattr__` methods of `obj` and `a` here are exactly the same, the difference (as Alex points out in the duplicate) is that there is no `__dict__`.